# Calculation stocked in a table MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, expression

I have 2 tables `TableA` and `TableB`.

In `TableA`, I have 3 columns (`Name`, `Stock` and `Price`).

In `TableB`, I have 2 columns (`NVariable` and `NFormula`). In TableB, I create a new variable that I give a name and I create the related formula base on `Price` of `TableA`.
For example, in `TableB`, I create a new variable called `Discount` and the formula is `0.15*Price`.

Now, I create the following query in Access:

```
SELECT Name, Stock, Price, NFormula AS Discount 
FROM TableA, TableB
```

and it shows me

```
Apple, 10, 10$, 0.15*Price
```

instead of

```
Apple, 10, 10$, 1.5
```

Please assist on this issue

Comment: MS Access is not the same as MySQL - please tag the correct database, and don't tag things which have nothing to do with your question. If you don't know the difference between Access and MySQL, please read the tag descriptions (and in future, read them _before_ using them) - thanks

Comment: P.S. The "access" tag is also incorrect for questions about Microsoft Access - again, I don't think you read the tag descriptions before using them, otherwise you'd have seen that fact made clear in the description. I've removed the incorrect tags for you on this occasion. I also edited the format of the question to make it much easier for people to read and understand quickly. In future please pay attention to this also, so that more people will be able to help you easily.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, columns cannot store "formulas". Actually, this ability is available in some databases (such as SQL Server), through the use of computed columns.  But it is not available in MS Access.

The solution is to use views. The structure would typically be to store the *discount ratio* in `TableB`:

```
CREATE VIEW v_ab AS
    SELECT a.Name, a.Stock, a.Price, 
           (b.discount_rate * a.Price) AS Discount 
    FROM TableA as a, TableB as b;
```

(Presumably, you want `INNER JOIN`, but that is not clear.)

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it doesn't work ! Do you have an idea with a query with VBA ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `discount` calculated field to `TableA` with expression as highlighted below.

[image]

---

Discount will be calculated automatically based on price field.

[image]

Comment: Hello Santosh, I can not see the image. Please can you reload it please ?

Comment: That's OK. But in my case, the end user creates which formula he wants based on Stock and Price and the system does the calculation automatically.  Do you have a idea on how this can be done ?

Comment: Ok, Modify `Discount` column as `Number` which will allow users to enter discount as per stock. They don't need to enter formula as it can be calculated in query once you have both info (price & discount rate)